# Extracting JVM stack trace from a heap dump (hprof) with a command line tool

Tags: jvm, devops, system-administration

I want to automate the extraction of the stack trace from the JVM crash heap dump file on a headless server. Is there a non-GUI solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) project comes with a script `ParseHeapDump.sh` (`*.bat` on Windows), if you just run it on a heap dump like this: `/path/to/MAT/ParseHeapDump.sh <HEAPDUMP_NAME>.hprof`, you get a set of files, one of them being a text file `<HEAPDUMP_NAME>.threads` containing stack traces, e.g.:

```
Thread 0x715883630

  locals:

Thread 0x71577b418
  at java.lang.Object.wait(J)V (Native Method)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(J)Ljava/lang/ref/Reference; (ReferenceQueue.java:155)
  at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run()V (CleanerImpl.java:148)
  at java.lang.Thread.run()V (Thread.java:834)
  at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run()V (InnocuousThread.java:134)

  locals:
    objectId=0x715833c30, line=1
    objectId=0x716df1990, line=1
    objectId=0x715832230, line=2
    objectId=0x71577b418, line=2
    objectId=0x71577b418, line=2
    objectId=0x71577b418, line=3
    objectId=0x71577b418, line=4

Thread 0x715883050
  at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(ZJ)V (Native Method)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V (LockSupport.java:234)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(J)J (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
  at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take()Ljava/util/concurrent/Delayed; (DelayQueue.java:229)
  at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AppDelayQueue.lambda$new$0()V (AppDelayQueue.java:26)
  at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AppDelayQueue$$Lambda$16.run()V (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run()V (Thread.java:834)

  locals:
    objectId=0x715883050, line=1
    objectId=0x715cd8a90, line=2
    objectId=0x7291c6618, line=2
    objectId=0x715f73520, line=3
    objectId=0x715cd8aa8, line=3
    objectId=0x715883050, line=3
    objectId=0x715f73520, line=4
    objectId=0x715cd8ac0, line=5
    objectId=0x715883050, line=6
...
```

You are only interested in lines starting with `Thread 0x...` and   `at ...` here.

Notes:

1. The script does a lot more work than would be necessary to only extract a thread dump (it parses the heap as well which is 99.99...% of work); and it generates many files that you do not need (all prefixed `<HEAPDUMP_NAME>`).
2. Thread names are lost, and thread ids seem to not correspond to anything OS-specific (e.g. native thread id); in other words, you cannot find `Thread 0x715883050` in the `ps` or `top`/`htop` output — at least I do not know a way.

Answer (score 0):

Open your heap dump in VisualVM
After the heap dump is loaded in the top left corner of the tab is a dropdown. Switch it to Threads.
Switch the thread view

Comment: The question was about a programmatic scripted way usable on a headless server.